# MySql & phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, openserver

У меня на компьютере установлен Open Server и с помощию его я запускаю вебстраницу из которой данные должны заноситься не в его базу данных, а в базу данных MySQL которая также установлена на моем компьютере. А данные всеравно записываются на базу созданию в phpmyadmin который установлен на Open Server-е.
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'a_db');

а это настройки по умолчанию phpmyadmin от Open Server. Я изменил только порт на 3307.
Server: 127.0.0.1:3307 »Database: a_db »Table: aa

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1.
В скрипте странички в функции подключения прописать порт той БД, в которую нужно писать данные.
Например:

```
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost:3307', 'root', 'root', 'a_db');
```

Вариант 2.
В настройках php в OpenServer есть строка

```
mysqli.default_port = %mysqlport%
```

её заменить на

```
mysqli.default_port = 3307
```

и перезагрузить OpenServer.
Данный вариант повлияет на все скрипты, выполняющиеся на OpenServer.

Comment: первый вариант не помог. а второй не хочу использовать, чтоб разобраться почему не могу использовать два SQL сервера.

Comment: Если необходимо помочь разобраться, то давайте больше информации. Первый вариант не помог - не получилось подключится? Всё равно пишет не в ту базу? Другая ошибка?
В нужную базу из консоли получается зайти?

Comment: Да, из консоли получается зайти и заполнить нужную базу. При добавлении порта :3307 на котором установлена база кида я хочу чтоб заносились дание выводит следующий ошибки:

Comment: Warning: mysqli::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in C:\OpenServer\domains\WEBSITE\check.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in C:\OpenServer\domains\WEBSITE\check.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in

Comment: C:\OpenServer\domains\WEBSITE\check.php on line 13
Код ошибки: 2054, ошибка: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Comment: Проблема в методе аутентификации базы mysql версий 8+. По умолчанию в версиях 8+ используется метод caching_sha2_password, необходимо поставить mysql_native_password. Нужно или переустановить сервер БД и при установке выбрать нужный тип аутентификации (support mysql 5+), или изменить тип аутентификации в настройках и пересоздать пользователей БД с данным типом аутентификации, либо изменить тип аутентификации у уже существующих пользователей.